# JSONObject inside an object is getting serialized to some other form as compared to a map

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, org.json, jackson-modules

**Why serialization is not working as expected for the JSONObject inside an Object ?**

```
class Random {
    String name;
    JSONObject json;
}
JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
json.put("key", "value");
Random random = new Random("name", json);
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(); ->
```

**Result** produces :  `{"name":"name", {"empty":false,"mapType":"java.util.HashMap"}}`

**Expected** result :  `{"name":"name", "json": {"key":"value"}}`

How to resolve this behaviour ?

Comment: The Expected result which you proposed is not a valid Json. Valid json would be something like this: {"name":"name","json":{"key":"value"}}

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Serializer: JSONObjectSerializer  and register it in ObjectMapper. Again assumption is that you are planning to have only a Map with key values in the "json" field.

```
record Random(String name, JSONObject json) {}

public class SerializerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("key", "value");
        Random random = new Random("name", json);
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(JSONObject.class, new JSONObjectSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(random);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static class JSONObjectSerializer extends StdSerializer<JSONObject> {

        public JSONObjectSerializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public JSONObjectSerializer(Class<JSONObject> t) {
            super(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(
            JSONObject value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            jgen.writeObject(value.toMap());
        }
    }
}
```

This code will produce output:

> {"name":"name","json":{"key":"value"}}

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to have only a Map with key values in the "json" field you can try this approach:

Instead of JSONObject keep a Map.

```
record Random (String name, Map json){}
```

The code to serialize will use json.toMap()

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key", "value");
Random random = new Random("name", json.toMap());
String s = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(random);
```

Comment: Yeah I can use Map but there's no way to Serialize the JSONObject here?

Comment: In that case I have added another answer which has more complex code but should do the job.